# Angular4 + TypeScript - setting "angular" object

Tags: angular

Just started with Angular4, using TypeScript and VS Code.

I'm having problems accessing "angular" object. For example trying to make `angular.element(".selector")` call - the object is null.

1. How can I initiate this object?
2. How can I set type interfaces for it?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. Without that I would recommend you go and do the tutorial provided on the angular.io website, it is very good.

Comment: Are you sure you are using angular4? `angular.element` is for angularjs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Do note that Angular is pretty much completely different from AngularJS, where you could do things like `angular.element(".selector")` and get something back. You should look into how to do things using the "Angular way", which is to say, using the model to drive the view.

Comment: I wonder what does the `angular.element` refers to? what is that your are trying to do!!

Comment: @echonax Yes, definitely using Angular4. Wa what would be then replacement for angular.element, JQLite selection ?

Comment: if you are planning to learn angular concepts check my repo and this url , explained all concepts in some brief  https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/

Comment: So I will try to summarize the answers:
-angular object is not present in the Angular4 anymore &&
-JQLite is not present in Angular4 anymore